# Under what hypotheses can a limit of presheaf categories, in $\mathsf{CAT}$, be computed as presheaves on a colimit

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose

$$ \mathsf{X}:\mathsf{J} \longrightarrow \mathsf{CAT} $$

factors through the functor

$$ \mathsf{Cat}^{\mathsf{op}} \longrightarrow \mathsf{CAT} $$

which sends a small category $\mathsf{A}$ to the category of presheaves $\widehat{\mathsf{A}}$ and sends a functor $f:\mathsf{A} \rightarrow \mathsf{B}$ to the inverse image functor $f^*:\widehat{\mathsf{B}} \rightarrow \widehat{\mathsf{A}}$. What further hypotheses are necessary so that the conical limit, in $\mathsf{CAT}$ of the diagram $\mathsf{X}$ may be computed as presheaves on the colimit of the factoring of $\mathsf{X}$ through $\mathsf{Cat}^{\mathsf{op}}$?

I know from "THE BICATEGORY OF TOPOI AND SPECTRA" by J. C. COLE ( http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/25/tr25.pdf ) that this works for some limits taken in the category of toposes, but the forgetful functor$\mathsf{Topos} \longrightarrow \mathsf{CAT}$ admits a right 2-adjoint, so in general those limits of toposes do not agree with the limits of the underlying categories.

However, this does work sometimes, for example:

- products (definitely) (take the coproduct before taking presheaves)
- op-lax limits of arrows (I think) (take the collage before taking presheaves)

but I'm really not clear on what's known about this question which seems like the sort of thing which is "well known".

Comment: Can you edit to give the author and title of the pdf you link to so people don't have to download it to check who you mean, if they are already familiar with the work?

Comment: Isn't that trivial as your functor $Cat^{op} \to CAT$ is representable as $Fun(\_ , Set)$ ?